# Retrieve Results from DB with Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I thought that this would be an easier thing to do, but I'm trying to get into better coding practices and I keep hearing that while is not a good way to loop results, so now I'm trying to switch and I thought I had it down, but no dice. My original code would have been

```
public function GetSiteName() {
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT site_name
FROM site_details
SQL;

$resource = $this->db->prepare( $query );
$resource->execute();
while($row = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['site_name'];
    }
}
```

So I've tried changing it to a foreach loop and I've gotten about a million different ways to do it using mysql extensions. (I'm fairly positive 99% of people would say it's better to use a while loop than go to mysql and use a deprecated function)
So instead what I'm trying isn't working

```
public function GetSiteName(){
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT site_name
FROM site_details
SQL;

$resource = $this->db->prepare( $query );
$resource->execute();
$result = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $detail){
echo $detail->site_name;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on here, the first one works just fine, but the second one gives me:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.d\db.class.php on line 37
```

However if I try running `print_r($result);` I get

```
Array ( [site_name] => Doxramos )
```

I think that's about as many details I can put, but I feel like I'm doing everything correct, but the Notice doesn't lie. I'm just not sure how it can say that on line 37 is trying to get a non object when I'm obviously pulling an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `echo` an object whilst `$detail` is an array. Change below

```
echo $detail->site_name;
```

To:

```
echo $detail['site_name'];
```

Comment: Well, I'll look into the new issue, but just so you know what I'm seeing now I get the error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'site_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.d\db.class.php on line 37
D` , It's kind of weird that it puts the D like it is trying to pull the site name. Turns out that the way it did work as an array pull was to instead use `$result['site_name']` I'm not sure what exactly is going on with it, but the foreach didn't seem to be doing too much, since I thought what I was trying to do was convert to an object, however your advice gave me the information I needed to fix it.

Comment: In the `foreach` loop what does `var_dump($detail)` give you ?

Comment: With var_dump I get `string(8) "Doxramos"` which isn't really what I was expecting, but it shows me while I couldn't fetch as an object or an array. and var_dump($result) Gives me `array(1) { ["site_name"]=> string(8) "Doxramos" }` I'm not sure why I would be able to get a valid result by using $result and not $detail within the foreach, but I do appreciate you putting me onto the right track.